# How to throw object on swipe without box2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am developing project that is based on throwing object on swipe,i have stone sprite and user will break glass bottle that randomly appear on screen using stone.

For ex. I have one stone sprite at ccp(512,225) this is fixed. Now when user touch object i get start point and on touchend i get end point. Then i calculate distance also. now i have to throw stone according to swipe direction and swipe speed. how can i achieve this.

I want to do this without any physics engine

[image]

Comment: I think what you want to look into is called 'ray casting' http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/raycast/

Comment: why u not tried with physics engine... it will more easy

Comment: I have not used Box2d yet and i dont have enough time to do R&D in Box2d otherwise no issue with box2d.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind that stone won't be accelerating then you can use `CCMoveTo`. The duration of action can be calculated by scheduling a function that measures duration of your swipe with interval of your desired precision. This is all based on assumption that you throw stone after touch ended.

Comment: I have calculated swipe time also but i have to throw stone according to swipe direction and swipe speed.how can i apply moveto in swipe direction and with swipe speed.

Comment: You have a point from touchended, right? then just use CCMoveTo with that point, and duration that was calculated and voila

Comment: I have end point and I use it in moveto like: `stone->runAction(ccMoveTo::create(duration,endpoint));` but how to pass “duration” according to swipe distance? Ex: I have swiped 500 pixel in 0.02 time now I have to calculate duration such that 1) more distance=more speed and 2) less swipe time =more speed.
So user swipe 500 pixel in .02 time then it will be faster then 500 pixel swiped in .05 second.Plz help me

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by duration? If you have 0.02 sec duration time then you have how long it takes to move a stone, right? I don't get what do you want to calculate more.